# Is there a way to remove everything from the target directory apart from the release binary?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Can `cargo clean` remove everything from the `target/` directory apart from the release binary? The default linking option in Rust is statically linked binaries, so dependencies are only there to improve recompilation/incremental.

AFAIK, `cargo clean` provides options to specify which target I want to clean up for. Is there a `cargo clean` flag that I am missing that does that?

Comment: cargo install ?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.

I'd just move the binary out of the `target` directory and then run `cargo clean`.